# Inline form shows up in Sonata page admin screen, but does not save

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I am building a new feature onto a Symfony 2.8 application using a few Sonata bundles.

My Page.orm.xml file now contains the following:

```
    <one-to-many target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Synonym" field="equivalents" mapped-by="page">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all/>
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
```

... while my Synonym.php entity definition contains the following:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="equivalents", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="page_id")
 */
private $page;
```

... and my PageAdmin.php file contains the following:

```
            ->add('equivalents', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Equivalents",
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Synonym',
                'admin_code' => 'app.admin.synonym',
            ))
```

So far so good. I can load my Page entity's admin screen and add new Synonym entities inline.

The problem comes when I save the Page entity and then reload it. The Synonym objects save, but they are no longer associated with the Page in question, so the Page reverts to having a blank area where the Synonym object listing should be.

**How do I make the Synonym objects remain associated with the Page object I am editing?**

Extra information in case it's handy: Running doctrine:schema:validate does not output any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my relationships on both the owning and inverse sides to many-to-many "fixed" the problem for me, in that I can now see relationships between records being persisted.

(This also involved creating a couple basic getters and setters that I had neglected earlier.)